# Button inside MultiAutoCompleteTextView Android Development

Tags: android, button

Anyone know how could I put Button inside my multiAutoCompleteTextView instead of a spannableString ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question... how do you want to put a button into a textview??
Could you explain a bit more your purpose please?

Comment: I wish instead of having simple words in my multiaucotompletetextview, having buttons in order to be able to clicked on them. 

Furthermore, this could be help me to sort out another problem which is that I would put drawablebackground in my multiautocompletetextview like this : 

http://www.casimages.com/img.php?i=10050704263087357.jpg

I hope, i'm more precise, and sorry for my loose english

Comment: I think you have to create your own widget, because AutoCompleteTextView is a subclass of textview. and button is not... You could try to add buttons to the adapter and see if it's working but i don't think it will

Answer (score 1):

In fact i try to add buttons with the adapter but it doesn't work.

Otherwise, Do you have another idea to put drawablebackground like this ? http://casimages.com/img.php?i=10050704263087357.jpg